# tmux not reading my .tmux.conf

Tags: command-line, 15.04, tmux

I have the following entries within my `.tmux.conf` in home directory

```
set-window-option -g xterm-keys on
set -g default-terminal screen-256color
set -g history-limit 10000
```

However an `echo $TERM` within a new `tmux` window  reports `tmux` and not `screen-256color`.
Even explicitly specifying the configuration file to be used via `tmux -f` has no effect. Also, `tmux` prints `Hello World` to the screen when it starts up so it appears to be using an alternate configuration file but I have no idea which one.

I have also verified that no previous `tmux` server instance is running at the time I start `tmux`

How do I get `tmux` to use `.tmux.conf` within my home directory?
I am using `tmux 2.0` (this same problem exists with `1.9.6` as well).

Note: I also have `byobu` setup in this environment

Comment: I have installed 1.9.6 and tested with your configuration. I have no problems. Without your configuration, `echo $TERM` says `screen` and with your configuration `screen-256color`

Comment: My start command: `tmux  -f .tmux.conf`

Comment: @A.B., I agree this is how it should work. I suspect the fact that I have byobu set up in my environment might have something to do with it.

Comment: In byobu I have this: `% tmux  -f .tmux.conf` --> `sessions should be nested with care, unset $TMUX to force`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my `.bash_profile` that was overriding $TERM. Since `tmux` starts the shell by default, settings from `.tmux.conf` can be overridden from the shell's profile file

Answer (score 2):

It is not advisable to embed `tmux` as nested session in `byobu`. Your configuration is correct and works. But not as session in `byobu`.

Comment: Thanks A.B. Will test this out once I get home from work